# Does the General Associativity Law follow from the Basic Associativity Law in the following General context? (Elementary Axiomatic Treatment)

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory, universal-algebra, associativity

Associative and commutative laws seem to permeate many areas. Hence, a general treatment may be of some use. In order to motivate the theory (which is necessary to even state the question), consider the following statement of a basic associative law:

$$[(a*b)*c] \cong [ a*(b*c)]$$

The specific nature of objects is irrelevant. In order to state the above, one only needs that there is a binary operation $*$ (Binary in the sense it operates on two inputs, however it could be partial binary operation as well) and there is a notion of **sameness**. Further, one may see that associativity only makes sense if the **expression's constituents** are the *same* and in the **same order**. So in the following, we aim to make these notions explicit.

**Primitives**

Countable (Possibly infinite) collection of atomic expressions(atoms): $a_1, a_2, ...$

Notion of sameness, an equivalence relation $\cong$

Notion of binary compatibility (a binary predicate) $\psi$

**Postulates**

P1: Let $e_1, e_2$ be expressions such that $\psi(e_1,e_2)$. Then $(e_1e_2)$ is also an expression. (Expression Construction Mechanism)

P2: Let $(e_1e_2)$ and $(e_3e_4)$ be expressions. If $e_1 \cong  e_3$ and $e_2 \cong e_4$, then $(e_1e_2) \cong (e_3e_4)$. (Substitution)

P3: Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be expressions. If $\psi(e_1, e_2) \wedge \psi(e_2, e_3)$, then $\psi(e_1, (e_2e_3)) \wedge \psi((e_1e_2),e_3)$. (Conservation of compatibility or two end postulate).

P4: Let $p$ be a predicate defined on expressions. If $p$ holds for all atomic expressions and $p(e_1) \wedge p(e_2) \Rightarrow p((e_1e_2))$ whenever $\psi(e_1, e_2)$, then $p$ holds for all expressions. (Induction Postulate)

P5: Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be expressions such that $\psi(e_1,e_2)$. It is postulated that for any expression $e_3$ such that $e_2 \cong e_3$, $\psi(e_1, e_3)$ and for any expression $e_4$ such that $e_1 \cong e_4$, $\psi(e_4,e_2)$. (Compatibility respects sameness)

P6: Let $e_1, e_2, e_3$ be expressions such that $\psi(e_1, e_2)$ and $\psi(e_2, e_3)$. It is postulated that $(e_1(e_2e_3)) \cong ((e_1e_2)e_3)$. (Associativity Axiom).

**Definitions**

D0: *Degree of Expression* is defined as following - if an expression e is atom, then $D(e) = 0$. Suppose $e_1$ and $e_2$  are expressions of degree $D(e_1)$ and $D(e_2)$ respectively. If $\psi(e_1, e_2)$, then $D((e_1e_2)) = max(D(e_1), D(e_2)) + 1$. By induction, one can show that this defines a degree for each expression.

D1: *Atomic sequence of a given expression*: For all atomic expressions e, $A(e) = e$ and $len(A(e)) = 1$. Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be expressions such that $A(e_1)$ and $A(e_2)$ are their respective atomic sequences with lengths $len(A(e_1))$ and $len(A(e_2))$ respectively. If $\psi(e_1,e_2)$, then $A((e_1e_2)) = A(e_1)A(e_2)$ and $len(A((e_1e_2))) = A(e_1) + A(e_2)$. Using expression equality on atomic terms, one is able to define equality on atomic sequences.

D2: *Atomically equivalent expressions*: Let $e_1, e_2$ be expressions. $e_1$ is said to be atomically equivalent if and only if $A(e_1) = A(e_2)$.

**Formulation of General Associativity**

Now we can formulate the general associativity as following: Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be expressions. If $e_1$ is atomically equivalent to $e_2$, then $e_1 \cong e_2$.

**Proof Ideas 0**

Consider the following atomically equivalent expressions: $e_1 = [((a_1a_2)(a_3a_4))((a_5a_6)(a_7a_8))], e_2 = [a_1(a_2(a_3(a_4(a_5(a_6(a_7a_8))))))]$. In line with our conventional way of proving, we start with $e_1$ and transform it using the basic associativity as follows:

Note that the expression $(a_7a_8)$ occurs in both $e_1$ and $e_2$. So, we can treat it as if it is also atomic.

$$t_1: [((a_1a_2)(a_3a_4))((a_5a_6)(a_7a_8))] \rightarrow [((a_1a_2)(a_3a_4))((a_5(a_6(a_7a_8))))]$$

It is valid transformation for a) from $e_2$ it follows that $\psi(a_6,(a_7a_8))$ and from conservation of compatibility it follows $\psi(a_5,(a_6(a_7a_8)))$; b) From P5 it follows that that $\psi(((a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)), ((a_5(a_6(a_7a_8))))$ as $((a_5a_6)(a_7a_8)) \cong (a_5(a_6(a_7a_8)))$. Similar ideas apply in the following transformations.

$$t_2: [((a_1a_2)(a_3a_4))((a_5(a_6(a_7a_8))))] \rightarrow [(a_1a_2)((a_3a_4)((a_5(a_6(a_7a_8)))))]$$

$$t_3: [(a_1a_2)((a_3a_4)((a_5(a_6(a_7a_8)))))] \rightarrow [(a_1a_2)(a_3(a_4(a_5(a_6(a_7a_8)))))]$$

$$t_5: [(a_1a_2)(a_3(a_4(a_5(a_6(a_7a_8)))))] \rightarrow [a_1(a_2(a_3(a_4(a_5(a_6(a_7a_8))))))]$$

**Questions**

Note that left-handed expressions such as $(((((((a_1a_2)a_3)a_4)a_5)a_6)a_7)a_8)$ don't always exist. Hence some new ideas are required.
Now the goal in which I've been struggling is the following: To distill some general elements from the above transformations which can possibly form the basis of a proof. One idea is that one should start from inside out i.e. one should start by building 1st degree expressions in the target and then second and so on.For example, I started by building the expression $(a_6(a_7a_8))$. But I don't know how to say all of this in a way which can form the basis of a proof.

Secondly, I wonder if there is a better, more natural way to phrase general associativity in general. It will great if somebody can help me.

Thirdly, perhaps most importanly, how can such a general theory apply in specific contexts, for example to show that basic associativity law for morphisms in a category implies the general associativity?

**P.S.**

1. I am not sure if I've tagged this question correctly. I am sorry. Please feel free to suggest appropriate tags.

Comment: I’m not sure why you want to axiomatize something as fundamental as an expression from the ground up. General associativity of some function $f:A\times A\to A$ says that each of the Catalan-number-many naturally induced functions $A\times \cdots \times \to A$ coincide.

Comment: Dear @KevinArlin Good question. On the surface, I would say that while learning about categories such as ETCS and general categories, I encountered many concepts (morphism composition, multiplication of objects, multiplication of categories) each of which required their own proof of general associativity. Hence, naturally I thought of encompassing everything in one single axiomatization which when and if applied would yield easy justification in all cases.

Comment: Furthermore, with beginning of my mathematical experience around 3 years, I was constantly dissatisfied with the level of rigor. While learning about graphs from "Distilling Ideas" https://bit.ly/2YpBjTx dissatisfied with the definition of sets, I encountered Lawvere and Schanuel's "Conceptual Mathematics" which was beautiful but which still left me wanting more rigor as I doubted my understanding of numbers which was nothing more than procedural. Perhaps, I am overly rigorous, I don't know. Hope somebody will set me straight if I am. I am sorry if this all read sentimental.

Comment: Dear @KevinArlin are you assuming that the binary operation is full, not partial? This formulation looks too specific, and it looks like it does not apply when equality is replaced by weaker notions of 'sameness'. I wonder how can this apply to say product operation defined on categories, or functor composition?

Comment: You should check out *monoidal categories* or *(unbiased) bicategories*.

Comment: I agree with Berci. These are different issues that need to be formalized in different ways. For general associativity of the product of $n$ objects in a category, you need to think about functors $A^n\to A$, and these questions are at the heart of coherence theory for monoidal categories. For partial operations, it's no big deal-if the operation is defined on $S\subset A^2$ then you get induced operations on the set of tuples $S_n\subset A^n$ such that every projection onto two adjacent entries lands. in $S$.

Comment: @KevinArlin I don't think I understand the way you see these as different issues. Could you explain how do you see them as different? In my view, they are just binary operations defined on objects, the nature of objects and specific context being irrelevant.

Comment: @jaspreet Because the product in a category is not a function, but a functor. So it doesn't fit into the standard formalism of binary operations. You can certainly include both these notions in the same general theory of operads, if you insist.

Comment: @KevinArlin Hence the axiomatic theory, which I see as not relying on seemingly superficial (Sorry about the choice of words, wish I could use weaker version of superficial.) distinctions such as functions and functors.

Comment: @jaspreet The reason it's not a superficial distinction, but in fact a highly meaningful one, is that one doesn't want to know simply that all bracketings of a product of objects are isomorphic in your category, but to know that they're *essentially uniquely* isomorphic. So your equivalence relation on expressions is not sufficiently refined.

Comment: @KevinArlin Good point. I see what you mean. I gotta think about it.

Comment: Coherence in monoidal categories is indeed stronger; let me rephrase what Kevin said in the last comment : it's not about wanting two expressions to be isomorphic, it's about all the natural isomorphisms built from assiciators between them being equal (see MacLane's pentagon). By the way, it could be interesting to note that your definition of atomic sequence of an expression strongly relies on generalized associativity for monoids.

Comment: @KevinArlin If you are interested, I've managed to find an enriched theory of expressions (with morphisms, to be precise) which builds upon the theory of expressions in order to express and prove natural isomorphicity of n-products and n-coproducts - I've also improved upon the rigour of presentation of theory of expressions - though still with some holes. You may (if interested) check it out here https://bit.ly/3i4ju37


Also, I am only a beginner in mathematical maturity, so I am completely ignorant of ideas such as operads (I hope I am mature enough some day to learn about them).